# Pushing changes to OpenShift

Tags: git, openshift

I'm following the tutorial below to push a change to my OpenShift application.

```
$ git clone <git_url> <directory_to_create>

# Within your project directory
# Commit your changes and push to OpenShift

$ git commit -a -m 'Some commit message'
$ git push
```

Instead of pushing changes to OpenShift, Git pushes to GitHub. How can I push the changes to OpenShift? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you `git clone`'d from GitHub, your Git remote will be set to push back to GitHub. You can change this remote to point to OpenShift:

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://YOURUSERID@foo-bar.rhcloud.com/~/git/foo.git/
```

You can get this URL from the OpenShift website for the specific domain in question.

Comment: Thank you, I found the repository; however, it gives me the (Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)) error.

Comment: @cagatayodabasi Did you [let OpenShift know about your public key](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/account)?

Comment: Yes, I just wrote 'rhc setup' and generated a new pair and it did the rest.

Answer (score 4):

By default, a cloned repository has a single remote (named `origin`, the source that it was cloned from), and the `master` branch has that remote's `master` branch set as its upstream. You can see a list of remotes by running `git remote -v` and a list of what branches have their upstreams set by running `git branch -vv`. When you push and pull, you are interacting with the upstream branch.

If you want to change where you push and pull from, you can do one of:

- Change the url of the `origin` remote ([as per hexafraction's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30418877/1267663)). This will override the GitHub URL with your new URL.
- Add a new remote (`git remote add openshift $url`) and push to that remote explicitly via:

  ```
  git push openshift master
  ```

  This will NOT change the default upstream and `git push` alone will still push to `origin`.
- Add a new remote (same as above) and set the upstream branch when pushing:

  ```
  git push -u openshift master
  ```

  This will set the upstream to `openshift/master`.

Comment: Definitely prefer to keep origin as it is and create a new remote called 'openshift'